# Calculation with timedifference in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate between now and a start time stored in x.

```
> x
[1] 2016-06-11T13:00Z 2016-06-11T19:00Z 2016-06-10T19:00Z 2016-06-11T16:00Z
```

When I now try

```
> difftime(Sys.time(), x, units="hours")
Time differences in hours
[1] -696.0873 -696.0873 -672.0873 -696.0873
```

Calculation only consider number of days and multiply with 24. I need exact amount of hours between now and event start.

Can someone please help..

Comment: Those look like indices from an xts object and as such are actually text. You should post `dput(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time difference can be directly calculated via `-` function which returns the difference in **seconds** which you can convert to **hours** dividing by 3600. As a demo:

```
> time1 <- Sys.time()
> time1
[1] "2016-05-12 22:23:58 EDT"
> time2 <- Sys.time()
> time2
[1] "2016-05-12 22:24:16 EDT"
> time2 - time1
Time difference of 17.79894 secs
> as.numeric(time2 - time1)/3600
[1] 0.004944149
```

So for your case, `as.numeric(x - Sys.time())/3600` should do the work for you. `round()` it to specific digit as you want.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you reply. I still get same amount of hours. 

> as.numeric(x - Sys.time())/3600
[1] -406424.2 -406424.2 -406424.2 -406424.2

Number of hours are also strange. It should roughly be 700 hours. Do I have to change format on time in x?

Comment: Your time is most likely incorrectly formatted.  The ~40600 hours is the elapsed time the beginning of time: Jan 1, 1970.  Please edit your question by providing a sample of your data using the "dput" command so we know exactly what your data is.

Comment: Try to use `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(x) - Sys.time())/3600` to convert your x to date time object first.

Comment: You latest comment solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)